# Which is the best framework in node js?

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

Hi i am making a whatsapp like app for this which framework suitable in node.i am new in node.js.So please suggest me framework which is suitable according to my requirement.

Thanks..

Comment: Probably because it's opinion-based and off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're new to Node.js, I would suggest [Express](http://expressjs.com) because it's easy to get started, has tons of examples, and it's quite powerful. It's used by some heavily loaded API and Web servers. This doesn't mean it's the best or anything like that. It's just suitable for beginners and can be used in production apps with no doubt.

Comment: Personally, I don't think there is the best framework. Considering how much community effort has already been invested into Express and how many middlewares already exist for this framework, I suppose it's the best one. Performance wise, there are faster solutions. However, in real projects often you don't consider minor performance improvements but instead consider the speed of development where Express perhaps leads the market due to its easy of getting started in many directions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to tell straight the best framework in nodejs (or in any other technologies). You can check out these.

Express.

[Restify.](https://www.npmjs.org/package/restify)

[Koajs](http://koajs.com)

[Geddy](http://geddyjs.org)